# Can you use a standard joist hanger connect lumber to an i-joist if I add stiffeners?

Tags: framing

I know they sell tabbed hangers for this but they want like $20 each for them. Just wondering how else people do this. Picture: I am in the middle of re-doing this and still need to remove the other header.

[image]

Comment: How was the girder originally fastened? What's a "tabbed" hanger? Do you mean a top-mount type?

Comment: Originally, just nailed. Sorry, top mount....
https://www.fastenersplus.com/Simpson-HUS210-2TF-Double-2x10-Top-Flange-Face-Mount-Hanger-G90-Galvanized

Answer (score 2):

I would carefully fit notched blocks the height of the joist into the cavity so they make contact on all faces. I'd also put a backer block between the ribs on the back side. Then I'd use construction glue and screws to anchor everything. Mount the hanger to that.

```
                    ________ __
                   |     ---|--|* <--- screws                    
                   |________|  |_
                   |   ||      | \
       screws --> *|---||---   |  \
                   |   ||      |   |
                  *|---||---   |   |
       backer ---->|   ||      |   |<-- joist hanger
                  *|---||---   |   |
                   |___||___   |   |
                   |        |  |   \
                   |________|__|____|
                             ^----------filler block
```

I'm not sure that it meets code, but I'd have confidence in it. Heck, if your face-nailed boards held up this will.

Comment: I'll be having an inspector come look (unfortunately) so I wonder if this is to code. Interesting idea though!

Comment: In my experience it's _fortunate_ that DIY framing is inspected. :) Then that's who you should be asking. (S)he should be happy to offer suggestions.

Comment: I'd put another filler piece of dim.lumber on the left of the OSB (where it says "screws"), to sandwich it and prevent pulling screws trough / buckling the sheet. Not sure if large washers would suffice. Otherwise it seems the top screw is taking all the pull-out force.

Comment: From what I recall of the vast pile of paperwork that came with my TJIs, you also want lumber glued and screwed to the other side of the web (where you show just screwheads) to block/sandwich the web securely from both sides. Or are you having those screws in space between the web and the block - that's not right. Blocks right up against the web, from flange to flange, both sides. OK; I think you just have the block notched out...

Comment: Yeah, I think you are allowed to add "stiffeners" (ply cut to fit 'inside' the i-joist) on both sides of the i-joist and then you can use standard joist hangers but it is tough information to find out there to confirm!

Comment: Good advice. I contemplated that while I was "drawing", and you've convinced me. Answer updated.